# MSExchange 2003 daylight time saving

Tags: exchange-2003

Yesterday we change the time zone (-1) all the computer syncs show the new time only exchange calender has the old time (+1) so every appointment is shown one hour head.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to ensure the Exchange server has updated the latest time zone update patch(es) - there's been quite a few...

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure your authoritative time server has all the recent time zone patches installed.

A similar thing like this happened to me a few weeks ago where all my time server updated itself a week early (old daylight savings time). When it originally updated it had no effect on the infrastructure, but when I tried to manually change the time on that server to the correct time it affected the timestamps on all my emails. My time server and Exchange server are two different servers, but because my Exchange server was getting it's time stamps from the time server and the time server was off it was affecting the times on other servers.

Answer (score 0):

For recurring meetings, and meeting created with Office 2003 sp3 and newer, you can use one of the method described in [kb931667](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931667) or [kb930879](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930879).

Single meetings that were created before Outlook 2003 sp3 will have to be corrected manually.